# Is there a way to replicate the functions from panelAR with plm or another package?

Tags: r, regression, panel-data, plm

I'm trying to replicate and expand on a study from 2011 that just so happens to be used as one of the demo
examples in the "panelAR" package. I don't know exactly how or why, but the demo code produces the exact same regression results from one section of the original study. One of the authors posted their replication code on their website, but it's in Stata, so I can't follow along in the "panelAR" demo code to understand how it accomplishes the same thing as the Stata code.

Here are the links to the original [STATA code](https://www.noamlupu.com/LupPon_APSR.do), [article](https://www.noamlupu.com/structure_inequality.pdf), and [data](https://www.noamlupu.com/LupPon_APSR.dta).

I've been able to successfully use the "panelAR" code to run regressions with my *new* data, but sadly "panelAR" objects are not compatible with "stargazer", which is the package I use to make my formatted tables.

All that said, is there a way to replicate the the following code using a different panel data package or combination of packages? I've tried using "plm", "pcse", and "nmle" but with no luck.

Below is the R code that runs the first regression model:

```
data(LupPon)
tibble(LupPon)

# A tibble: 858 x 14
   country      id  year redist ratio9050 ratio5010 ratio9010  skew turnout fempar propind  pvoc union unempl
   <chr>     <int> <int>  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 Australia     1  1960     NA        NA        NA        NA    NA      NA     NA      NA    NA    NA     NA
 2 Australia     1  1961     NA        NA        NA        NA    NA      NA     NA      NA    NA    NA     NA
 3 Australia     1  1962     NA        NA        NA        NA    NA      NA     NA      NA    NA    NA     NA
 4 Australia     1  1963     NA        NA        NA        NA    NA      NA     NA      NA    NA    NA     NA
 5 Australia     1  1964     NA        NA        NA        NA    NA      NA     NA      NA    NA    NA     NA
 6 Australia     1  1965     NA        NA        NA        NA    NA      NA     NA      NA    NA    NA     NA
 7 Australia     1  1966     NA        NA        NA        NA    NA      NA     NA      NA    NA    NA     NA
 8 Australia     1  1967     NA        NA        NA        NA    NA      NA     NA      NA    NA    NA     NA
 9 Australia     1  1968     NA        NA        NA        NA    NA      NA     NA      NA    NA    NA     NA
10 Australia     1  1969     NA        NA        NA        NA    NA      NA     NA      NA    NA    NA     NA
# … with 848 more rows

    
LupPon <- LupPon[!is.na(LupPon$redist),]
    
LupPon$redist.lag <- unlist(by(LupPon,LupPon$id,function(x){c(NA,x[,"redist"]
[1:(length(x[,"redist"])-1)])}))
    
LupPon$time <- unlist(by(LupPon,LupPon$id,function(x) seq(1:nrow(x))))
    
out1 <- panelAR(redist ~ redist.lag + ratio9050 + ratio5010 + turnout + fempar + propind + 
pvoc + union + unempl, data=LupPon, panelVar='id', timeVar='time', autoCorr='ar1',
panelCorrMethod='pcse',rho.na.rm=TRUE, panel.weight='t-1', bound.rho=TRUE)
    
summary(out1
```

```
    Panel Regression with AR(1) Prais-Winsten correction and panel-corrected standard errors

Unbalanced Panel Design:                                               
 Total obs.:       68 Avg obs. per panel 4.5333
 Number of panels: 15 Max obs. per panel 9     
 Number of times:  9  Min obs. per panel 1     

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -3.26666   11.15944  -0.293 0.770776    
redist.lag   0.50658    0.12652   4.004 0.000179 ***
ratio9050    3.81044    3.35976   1.134 0.261402    
ratio5010   -4.76833    2.06327  -2.311 0.024405 *  
turnout      0.09781    0.03644   2.684 0.009454 ** 
fempar       0.09134    0.05464   1.672 0.099973 .  
propind      0.07253    2.54464   0.029 0.977360    
pvoc         0.01860    0.03668   0.507 0.613909    
union        0.08862    0.03736   2.372 0.021029 *  
unempl       0.12415    0.13443   0.923 0.359580    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-squared: 0.8886
Wald statistic: -708.2314, Pr(>Chisq(9)): 1
```

Edit 2: And here's the STATA code that also runs the first regression model:

```
** Redistribution models (Table 2)

preserve
keep if redist!=.
sort id year
by id: egen order = seq()
tsset id order

xtpcse redist l1.redist dvpratio9050 dvpratio5010 dvturnout dvfempar dvstddisp_gall dvpvoc dvunion dvunempl, pairwise cor(ar1)
predict pred if e(sample), xb
gen resid = redist-pred
egen stresid=std(resid)
gen outlier = 0 if e(sample)
replace outlier = 1 if abs(stresid)>1.5
```

Edit 3: Below are the all of the code chunks for the next 7 regression models in both R and STATA

```
#### Regressions in R
# Removing outliers...
mod1.resid <- out1$residuals
index <- which(abs((mod1.resid-mean(mod1.resid))/sd(mod1.resid)) <= 1.5)
LupPon.nooutlier <- out1$model[index,]> out2 <- panelAR(redist ~ redist.lag + ratio9050 + ratio5010 + turnout + fempar + propind + pvoc + union + unempl, data=LupPon.nooutlier, panelVar='id', timeVar='time', autoCorr='ar1', panelCorrMethod='pcse',rho.na.rm=TRUE, panel.weight='t-1', bound.rho=TRUE)
The following units have non-consecutive observations. Use runs.analysis() on output for additional details: 12, 15, 16, 17, 4, 6.
Panel-specific correlations bounded to [-1,1]
summary(out2)

Panel Regression with AR(1) Prais-Winsten correction and panel-corrected standard errors

Unbalanced Panel Design:                                               
 Total obs.:       58 Avg obs. per panel 3.8667
 Number of panels: 15 Max obs. per panel 8     
 Number of times:  9  Min obs. per panel 1     

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.57080    7.27261   0.078   0.9378    
redist.lag   0.49404    0.07800   6.333 7.74e-08 ***
ratio9050    6.04188    2.81801   2.144   0.0371 *  
ratio5010   -6.58628    1.32426  -4.974 8.82e-06 ***
turnout      0.06427    0.02554   2.516   0.0153 *  
fempar       0.07852    0.03606   2.178   0.0344 *  
propind     -2.46670    2.05462  -1.201   0.2358    
pvoc         0.01582    0.02327   0.680   0.4999    
union        0.12558    0.01634   7.686 6.59e-10 ***
unempl       0.04132    0.10911   0.379   0.7066    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-squared: 0.931
Wald statistic: 2323.5873, Pr(>Chisq(9)): 0


out3 <- panelAR(redist ~ ratio9050 + ratio5010 + as.factor(id), data=LupPon, panelVar='id', timeVar='time', autoCorr='ar1', panelCorrMethod='pcse',rho.na.rm=TRUE, panel.weight='t-1', bound.rho=TRUE)
Panel-specific correlations bounded to [-1,1]
summary(out3)

Panel Regression with AR(1) Prais-Winsten correction and panel-corrected standard errors

Unbalanced Panel Design:                                               
 Total obs.:       77 Avg obs. per panel 5.1333
 Number of panels: 15 Max obs. per panel 10    
 Number of times:  10 Min obs. per panel 1     

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)      13.97114    9.87777   1.414 0.162412    
ratio9050        14.05312    4.99515   2.813 0.006619 ** 
ratio5010        -8.13602    4.90541  -1.659 0.102420    
as.factor(id)3   13.18767    1.50276   8.776 2.36e-12 ***
as.factor(id)4   -0.69241    2.81607  -0.246 0.806616    
as.factor(id)5   11.97750    2.20502   5.432 1.07e-06 ***
as.factor(id)6   10.30933    1.94688   5.295 1.78e-06 ***
as.factor(id)7   -2.09143    1.43608  -1.456 0.150511    
as.factor(id)8   -1.66623    1.03527  -1.609 0.112766    
as.factor(id)9   -0.07301    2.12339  -0.034 0.972686    
as.factor(id)12   6.05386    1.73534   3.489 0.000916 ***
as.factor(id)14   8.45693    1.95346   4.329 5.77e-05 ***
as.factor(id)15  13.59385    2.24826   6.046 1.03e-07 ***
as.factor(id)16 -12.92293    1.34996  -9.573 1.09e-13 ***
as.factor(id)17  -2.62601    1.37326  -1.912 0.060623 .  
as.factor(id)18  -9.95612    2.26996  -4.386 4.74e-05 ***
as.factor(id)20 -13.69930    2.20810  -6.204 5.59e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-squared: 0.8806
Wald statistic: 189246.9165, Pr(>Chisq(16)): 0


# Removing outliers...
mod3.resid <- out3$residuals
index <- which(abs((mod3.resid-mean(mod3.resid))/sd(mod3.resid)) <= 1.5)
LupPon.nooutlier <- out3$model[index,]> out4 <- panelAR(redist ~ ratio9050 + ratio5010 + as.factor(id), data=LupPon.nooutlier, panelVar='id', timeVar='time', autoCorr='ar1', panelCorrMethod='pcse',rho.na.rm=TRUE, panel.weight='t-1', bound.rho=TRUE)
The following units have non-consecutive observations. Use runs.analysis() on output for additional details: 12, 15, 17, 4, 5, 6.
Panel-specific correlations bounded to [-1,1]
summary(out4)

Panel Regression with AR(1) Prais-Winsten correction and panel-corrected standard errors

Unbalanced Panel Design:                                               
 Total obs.:       68 Avg obs. per panel 4.5333
 Number of panels: 15 Max obs. per panel 8     
 Number of times:  10 Min obs. per panel 1     

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)      20.6537     6.0314   3.424  0.00122 ** 
ratio9050         9.8536     3.2130   3.067  0.00346 ** 
ratio5010        -7.7280     4.0575  -1.905  0.06248 .  
as.factor(id)12   6.8209     1.5622   4.366 6.19e-05 ***
as.factor(id)14   7.1422     1.6633   4.294 7.87e-05 ***
as.factor(id)15  11.7269     1.3660   8.585 1.79e-11 ***
as.factor(id)16 -13.1042     1.3083 -10.016 1.22e-13 ***
as.factor(id)17  -2.3581     1.0988  -2.146  0.03664 *  
as.factor(id)18  -8.6729     1.5719  -5.518 1.16e-06 ***
as.factor(id)20 -12.3829     1.4979  -8.267 5.57e-11 ***
as.factor(id)3   12.6117     1.1372  11.091 3.37e-15 ***
as.factor(id)4   -1.8655     2.2007  -0.848  0.40057    
as.factor(id)5   12.7513     0.8727  14.612  < 2e-16 ***
as.factor(id)6    8.6724     0.8584  10.102 9.10e-14 ***
as.factor(id)7   -1.1486     1.0426  -1.102  0.27575    
as.factor(id)8   -1.7659     1.0488  -1.684  0.09833 .  
as.factor(id)9    0.6549     1.6795   0.390  0.69822    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-squared: 0.9517
Wald statistic: 5785762.7106, Pr(>Chisq(16)): 0


out5 <- panelAR(redist ~ redist.lag + ratio9010 + skew + turnout + fempar + propind + pvoc + union + unempl, data=LupPon, panelVar='id', timeVar='time', autoCorr='ar1', panelCorrMethod='pcse',rho.na.rm=TRUE, panel.weight='t-1', bound.rho=TRUE)
Panel-specific correlations bounded to [-1,1]
summary(out5)

Panel Regression with AR(1) Prais-Winsten correction and panel-corrected standard errors

Unbalanced Panel Design:                                               
 Total obs.:       68 Avg obs. per panel 4.5333
 Number of panels: 15 Max obs. per panel 9     
 Number of times:  9  Min obs. per panel 1     

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -14.73371    9.19697  -1.602 0.114585    
redist.lag    0.49211    0.12412   3.965 0.000204 ***
ratio9010    -0.01548    1.13592  -0.014 0.989172    
skew         10.17135    3.67271   2.769 0.007529 ** 
turnout       0.10182    0.03629   2.806 0.006819 ** 
fempar        0.08536    0.05333   1.601 0.114901    
propind      -0.06816    2.45060  -0.028 0.977905    
pvoc          0.01991    0.03702   0.538 0.592875    
union         0.09013    0.03607   2.499 0.015316 *  
unempl        0.11177    0.13563   0.824 0.413280    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-squared: 0.8918
Wald statistic: -151.0228, Pr(>Chisq(9)): 1


# Removing outliers...
mod5.resid <- out5$residuals
index <- which(abs((mod5.resid-mean(mod5.resid))/sd(mod5.resid)) <= 1.5)
LupPon.nooutlier <- out5$model[index,]> out6 <- panelAR(redist ~ redist.lag + ratio9010 + skew + turnout + fempar + propind + pvoc + union + unempl, data=LupPon.nooutlier, panelVar='id', timeVar='time', autoCorr='ar1', panelCorrMethod='pcse',rho.na.rm=TRUE, panel.weight='t-1', bound.rho=TRUE)
The following units have non-consecutive observations. Use runs.analysis() on output for additional details: 12, 15, 16, 17, 4, 6.
Panel-specific correlations bounded to [-1,1]
summary(out6)

Panel Regression with AR(1) Prais-Winsten correction and panel-corrected standard errors

Unbalanced Panel Design:                                               
 Total obs.:       58 Avg obs. per panel 3.8667
 Number of panels: 15 Max obs. per panel 8     
 Number of times:  9  Min obs. per panel 1     

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -12.43089    6.18074  -2.011   0.0499 *  
redist.lag    0.48096    0.07362   6.533 3.83e-08 ***
ratio9010    -0.16200    0.94572  -0.171   0.8647    
skew         12.98571    2.58573   5.022 7.48e-06 ***
turnout       0.06363    0.02581   2.466   0.0173 *  
fempar        0.07440    0.03485   2.135   0.0379 *  
propind      -2.37649    1.93445  -1.229   0.2252    
pvoc          0.01183    0.02326   0.509   0.6134    
union         0.12312    0.01525   8.073 1.71e-10 ***
unempl        0.05119    0.10653   0.480   0.6331    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-squared: 0.9346
Wald statistic: 2147.9426, Pr(>Chisq(9)): 0

out7 <- panelAR(redist ~ ratio9010 + skew + as.factor(id), data=LupPon, panelVar='id', timeVar='time', autoCorr='ar1', panelCorrMethod='pcse',rho.na.rm=TRUE, panel.weight='t-1', bound.rho=TRUE)
Panel-specific correlations bounded to [-1,1]
summary(out7)

Panel Regression with AR(1) Prais-Winsten correction and panel-corrected standard errors

Unbalanced Panel Design:                                               
 Total obs.:       77 Avg obs. per panel 5.1333
 Number of panels: 15 Max obs. per panel 10    
 Number of times:  10 Min obs. per panel 1     

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)      -4.6646     8.6392  -0.540 0.591242    
ratio9010         1.3439     1.5360   0.875 0.385089    
skew             24.4739     7.5166   3.256 0.001860 ** 
as.factor(id)3   12.3092     1.3360   9.214 4.32e-13 ***
as.factor(id)4   -0.0509     2.7927  -0.018 0.985518    
as.factor(id)5   11.0080     2.1338   5.159 2.95e-06 ***
as.factor(id)6    9.0069     1.9432   4.635 1.97e-05 ***
as.factor(id)7   -2.6626     1.2938  -2.058 0.043947 *  
as.factor(id)8   -1.6262     0.9011  -1.805 0.076137 .  
as.factor(id)9    0.6049     2.1973   0.275 0.784038    
as.factor(id)12   5.9046     1.6921   3.490 0.000913 ***
as.factor(id)14   7.9706     1.7490   4.557 2.60e-05 ***
as.factor(id)15  11.9357     2.3695   5.037 4.62e-06 ***
as.factor(id)16 -12.8997     1.5345  -8.406 9.96e-12 ***
as.factor(id)17  -2.1192     1.3775  -1.538 0.129196    
as.factor(id)18  -9.3785     2.2897  -4.096 0.000128 ***
as.factor(id)20 -13.1480     2.2069  -5.958 1.45e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-squared: 0.8874
Wald statistic: 63452.5759, Pr(>Chisq(16)): 0

# Removing outliers...
mod7.resid <- out7$residuals
index <- which(abs((mod7.resid-mean(mod7.resid))/sd(mod7.resid)) <= 1.5)
LupPon.nooutlier <- out7$model[index,]> out8 <- panelAR(redist ~ ratio9010 + skew + as.factor(id), data=LupPon.nooutlier, panelVar='id', timeVar='time', autoCorr='ar1', panelCorrMethod='pcse',rho.na.rm=TRUE, panel.weight='t-1', bound.rho=TRUE)
The following units have non-consecutive observations. Use runs.analysis() on output for additional details: 12, 15, 17, 4, 5, 6.
Panel-specific correlations bounded to [-1,1]
summary(out8)

Panel Regression with AR(1) Prais-Winsten correction and panel-corrected standard errors

Unbalanced Panel Design:                                               
 Total obs.:       67 Avg obs. per panel 4.4667
 Number of panels: 15 Max obs. per panel 8     
 Number of times:  10 Min obs. per panel 1     

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       3.8009     5.5166   0.689  0.49402    
ratio9010        -1.5372     0.9529  -1.613  0.11298    
skew             24.4161     5.8523   4.172  0.00012 ***
as.factor(id)12   6.1617     1.4439   4.267 8.80e-05 ***
as.factor(id)14   5.0717     1.4991   3.383  0.00140 ** 
as.factor(id)15   8.3799     1.3962   6.002 2.17e-07 ***
as.factor(id)16 -14.9084     1.2974 -11.491 1.22e-15 ***
as.factor(id)17  -0.7629     1.0720  -0.712  0.47999    
as.factor(id)18  -5.5874     1.5338  -3.643  0.00064 ***
as.factor(id)20  -9.3915     1.5103  -6.218 1.00e-07 ***
as.factor(id)3   10.5130     1.0326  10.181 8.77e-14 ***
as.factor(id)4    1.4597     2.0448   0.714  0.47862    
as.factor(id)5   10.6512     0.8865  12.015 2.35e-16 ***
as.factor(id)6    6.2242     1.0314   6.035 1.93e-07 ***
as.factor(id)7   -1.5296     0.7421  -2.061  0.04451 *  
as.factor(id)8   -1.7578     0.7908  -2.223  0.03079 *  
as.factor(id)9    3.7324     1.7773   2.100  0.04079 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-squared: 0.9683
Wald statistic: 1080793.3476, Pr(>Chisq(16)): 0
```

```
# Regressions in STATA
xtpcse redist l1.redist dvpratio9050 dvpratio5010 dvturnout dvfempar dvstddisp_gall dvpvoc dvunion dvunempl if outlier!=1, pairwise cor(ar1) hetonly
drop pred resid stresid outlier

xi: xtpcse redist dvpratio9050 dvpratio5010 i.id, pairwise cor(ar1)
predict pred if e(sample), xb
gen resid = redist -pred
egen stresid=std(resid)
gen outlier = 0 if e(sample)
replace outlier = 1 if abs(stresid)>1.5

xi: xtpcse redist dvpratio9050 dvpratio5010 i.id if outlier!=1, pairwise cor(ar1)
drop pred resid stresid outlier

xtpcse redist l1.redist dvratio9010 dvskew dvturnout dvfempar dvstddisp_gall dvpvoc dvunion dvunempl, pairwise cor(ar1)
predict pred if e(sample), xb
gen resid = redist -pred
egen stresid=std(resid)
gen outlier = 0 if e(sample)
replace outlier = 1 if abs(stresid)>1.5

xtpcse redist l1.redist dvratio9010 dvskew dvturnout dvfempar dvstddisp_gall dvpvoc dvunion dvunempl if outlier!=1, pairwise cor(ar1)
drop pred resid stresid outlier

xi: xtpcse redist dvratio9010 dvskew i.id, pairwise cor(ar1)
predict pred if e(sample), xb
gen resid = redist -pred
egen stresid=std(resid)
gen outlier = 0 if e(sample)
replace outlier = 1 if abs(stresid)>1.5

xi: xtpcse redist dvratio9010 dvskew i.id if outlier!=1, pairwise cor(ar1)
drop pred resid stresid outlier

restore
```

Comment: Maybe you would like to put the link to the Stata code in your post as well.

Comment: @Helix123 thanks for the advice. The STATA code is now included and linked to.

Answer (score 0):

If your main concern is to export your formatted tables, then it is much easier to replace stargazer with texreg instead of replicating the results using other packages. From my experience, texreg package supports panelAR objects. For example: screenreg(list(panelAR_model1, panelAR_model2)) will show a formatted table in the console, so you can check the output, while texreg(list(panelAR_model1, panelAR_model2)) will produce a latex table. See the texreg documentation for customization.